# Make the area surrounding the text larger when zooming out

Tags: html, css

I want the black area surrounding my text to become larger when zooming out, rather than there
becoming a white area to the right of my text, which is what is currently happening. I have tried to set width:auto; on the two div's, but then the black part disappeared altogether. Here is my html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet.css">
    <title>lorem</title>
</head>
<body>
        <p style="white-space: nowrap">
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum nec ipsum aliquam enim faucibus ultricies ut imperdiet ex. Phasellus ut quam sed velit ultrices tempor non eget urna. In vehicula sodales ante ut malesuada. In odio elit, congue a gravida id, semper non tellus.
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
        </p>
    <div class="div1">
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the css part:

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Consolas";
src: url("Consolas.ttf");
}

*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
main {
    position: relative;
}
 p{
     display: inline-block;
    font-size:15px;
    font-family: "Consolas";
    margin: 0 3px;
    width: 900px;
    position:relative;

}
.div1{
    background-color: black;
    float: right;
    height: 40000px;
    width: 50px;
}
.div2{
    background-color: black;
    float: left;
    height: 40000px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

I hope these three pictures will help clarify the problem. When I zoom out on the text which I have uploaded to my website, rather than the black part to the right of the text filling out the increasing space, it is filled out by a blank white space. That is, I would like the part I have drawn with red on in the pictures to be black instead of white...

> the one where I haven't zoomed out
>   [image: the one where I haven't zoomed out]
>   the one where I have zoomed out to 90%
>   [image: the one where I have zoomed out to 90%]
>   the one where I have zoomed out to 70%
>   [image: the one where I have zoomed out to 70%]

I am a bit of a novice and had a friend help me with the code, so I realize that I may be completely on the wrong track, but thanks in advance :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow _ We'll need to see some of the HTML as well _ Check out these guidelines on how to post a Minimal Reproducible Example >>> https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I have updated it with the html part now :)

Comment: Can you describe your desire more clearly, I would love to help but happened to can't understand. Any images, gifs are very welcome.

Comment: I have added three images now - I hope that makes it clearer what my problem is..

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean browser zoom?

```
    .zoom
{
    zoom: 150%;
    background-color: black;
    */ your remaining styles*/

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I modified your html markup and use flexbox to achieve something similar to what (i hope) you mean:

```css
.demo { 
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  background: black; 
}
.demo p {
  padding-top: 50vh;
  background: white;
  min-width: 900px; 
  margin: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x:  auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
.demo div {width: 50px; background: black;}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vestibulum nec ipsum aliquam enim faucibus ultricies ut imperdiet ex. Phasellus ut quam sed velit ultrices tempor non eget urna. In vehicula sodales ante ut malesuada. In odio elit, congue a gravida id, semper non tellus.</p>
  <div class="div2"></div>
</div>
```

If something isn't clear feel free to ask and i will gladly answer. Enjoy code!

Comment: I think it works. Thank you - you're a lifesaver! And merry Christmas!

Comment: No problems, enjoy the holiday!